# Heroku SSH error:

Tags: heroku

I was following the Eclipse Heroku tutorial and trying to create an app. However for the past three hours i have gotten the following  error:

We have encountered a problem creating your application: fierce-atoll-8131. This could be due to the Eclipse SSH key is not matching the SSH key(s) that is associated with your Heroku account. To fix this error, you can:

- Associate your SSH key to your Heroku account by going to "Preferences"
  OR
- If the SSH Key is correct, restart Eclipse.
  git@heroku.com:fierce-atoll-8131.git: reject HostKey: Heroku.com

I have perused Google and all the forums for this, yet there is no fix, Heroku also seems oblivious to it, as they have not offered any solution. I have deleted my keys, made new ones, used the toolbelt. I'm beginning to think its a bug, and that Heroku simply ignores it or doesn't know.

The error also occurs when creating an app on the Java.Heroku site and trying to import it into Eclipse. As I mentioned I followed the Tutorial here on Heroku, about getting started with Eclipse, so I would appreciate NOT being pointed at it for answers as it does not have any solution.

I am running on Windows 7 64bit with Eclipse Kepler

Answer (score 24):

The problem is caused because Heroku plugin does not add a known hosts entry for heroku.com and git clone fails.

To solve this issue go to File -> Import... -> Projects from Git. Then select URI, click next and put you project URI in the URI field (i.e. git@heroku.com:fierce-atoll-8131.git) and click next. Then you will be asked to add heroku.com fingerprint to the known hosts list and create the known hosts file if it doesn't exist. After you accept this, you can cancel the Git import and proceed with Heroku plugin import.

Comment: What if I am creating a new project? There is nothing to clone. The problem also occured.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks WinterN
I too ran with the same problem on Windows 7. Couldn't yet get it working!
But I tried on Centos 6.4 x86_64 VM. Kept getting the same error.
Finally did what you suggested.

```
$ssh git@heroku.com
```

and it added the heroku key to `knownhosts` file Restarted git.

First tried to import an existing  project form Heroku, Succeeded!

Next create -> new -> Heroku template succeeded!

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I've experienced this problem the reason was that I had two SSH-RSA keys with the same "Comment".

Log into your Heroku account dashboard on the web (https://dashboard.heroku.com/account), and look under the section for SSH Keys. If you see more than one with the same comment (RSA-1024 seems to be the default for SSH2 key generation in eclipse), remove the ones you aren't using (you'll want to look in each eclipse setup you have that's working for the ones you're using, or you can just clear them all out and set up the SSH-RSA again using eclipse). Then, when you generate a new RSA key, put `username@computer` in the comment, and add that to Heroku.

Once you've cleared out the duplicate keys from your Heroku dashboard, you can generate a new key in the eclipse you're setting up by doing the following:

1. Eclipse preferences, General->Network Connections->SSH2
2. Key Management tab
3. Generate RSA Key
4. Enter user@computer in "Comment" field in place of RSA-1024
5. Select Apply to save the file

Then add the key to Heroku:

1. Eclipse preferences, Heroku
2. (Login to get API key if not already populated)
3. Select Load SSH Key
4. open the file you saved earlier
5. Select Add
6. Apply, OK

Hope this helps!